# How can I display the first and last child record for a parent row in Rails 3.1?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm rather new to Rails and simply love it's expressive modeling architecture. I'm currently building a routing system with a one to many link between two tables.

Consider the following schema:

```
class CreateTrips < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :trips do |t|
      t.string :name
    end
  end
  ...
end


class CreatePitStop < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :pit_stops do |t|
      t.references :trip
      t.integer :stop_number
      t.string :location
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Now consider the following data for a single trip:

```
t = Trips.create!({ :name => "Christmas Visits Route" })
t.pit_stops.create!({ :stop_number => 1, :location => "Home" })
t.pit_stops.create!({ :stop_number => 2, :location => "Mom and Dads" })
t.pit_stops.create!({ :stop_number => 3, :location => "In-Laws" })
t.pit_stops.create!({ :stop_number => 4, :location => "Grandma's" })
t.pit_stops.create!({ :stop_number => 5, :location => "Time Square" })
```

What I'd like to do is show a list of all trip Name along with the Location of first and last PitStop in a single "trip" row for the 'trips/index' view. I don't care about the pit stops in between, I just want to know where I started and where I ended:

```
--------
My Trips
--------

--------------------------------------------------------
| Route Name              | From   | To                |
--------------------------------------------------------
| Christmas Visits Route  | Home   | Time Square       |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I'd like to eliminate all the "in-between" PitStops from the query, as there will be quite a few for each Trip.

**Question**: What is the best way to pull this data from the db using ActiveRecord?

## Solution: Jan. 3rd, 2012

I solved my problem by applying my PitStop logic to the Trip model. My From and To PitStops now have hard coded stop_number values. After working through it, I found that the solution actually makes sense for the real world as well (double win).

- The **From** PitStop record will always have a stop_number value of 0.
- The **To** PitStop record will always have a stop_number value of 99.

This makes sense because the first PitStop isn't really a "pit stop" at all, it's where you start from (ie. 0). The last PitStop isn't really a "pit stop" either, it's your end location (ie. 99). Of course this assumes that no route will ever have more than 98 "pit stops". :) Safe assumption for me...

These logically defined "stop_numbers" also solve my problem for querying all child PitStops for the 'trips/index' display, and I can query these values quickly and effectively per trip (no more sub queries for `.first` or `.last`):

```
class Trip
  has_many :pit_stops
  has_one :starting_from, :class => 'PitStop', 
          :conditions => 'pit_stops.stop_number == 0'
  has_one :ending_at, :class => 'PitStop', 
          :conditions => 'pit_stops.stop_number == 99'

  def add_pit_stop(location)
    stop_num = @pit_stops.count - 1 # accounts for stop_number 99
    @pit_stops.create!({ :stop_number => stop_num, 
                         :location => location})
  end
end
```

As you see, the trick to entering the `stop_numbers` is now a simple math equation after defining your **starting_from** and **ending_at** records (now a logical business rule). Now I can simply say:

```
trip = create_trip("Christmas Visits", "Home", "Time Square")
trip.add_pit_stop("Mom and Dads")
trip.add_pit_stop("In-Laws")
trip.add_pit_stop("Grandma's")
```

My (ordered) PitStop records now look like this:

```
{ :stop_number => 0, :location => "Home" }
{ :stop_number => 1, :location => "Mom and Dads" }
{ :stop_number => 2, :location => "In-Laws" }
{ :stop_number => 3, :location => "Grandma's" }
{ :stop_number => 99, :location => "Time Square" }
```

Very elegant in my opinion. Thanks [@clyfe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283608/clyfe) for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add two extra relations to the Trip class:

```
clss Trip
  has_many :pit_stops
  has_one :start_pit_stop, :class => 'PitStop', 
    :conditions => 'pit_stops.order_number == 1'
  has_one :end_pit_stop, :class => 'PitStop', 
    :conditions => 'pit_stops.order_number == trips.last_order_number'
end
```

For the start put_stop you can condition on == 1, for the last one you need an extra column on the `trips` table where you cache the last trip number. You could also cache the ids for these two pit_stops on the parent. **This way you can do eager load.**

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it is ok to do it in two db trips, you could use

```
first_stop = t.pit_stops.order(:stop_number).first
last_stop = t.pit_stops.order(:stop_number).reverse_order.first
```

Comment: Thanks. I now see that this is very similar to @Durrant's suggestion, but more expressive. I appreciate the effort, however I fear this too would require that I query the full list of pit_stops and then retrieve the first and last (by reversing the order and getting the first). :) Thanks for the thought... Again, I'm looking for a way to QUERY the first and last in a single query. Any other ideas?